# ActiveMQ Hawtio Dashboard is too slow to work with

Tags: jms, activemq-classic, hawtio

I'm using Hawtio console via a browser

```
http://localhost:8161/hawtio/#/dashboard/
```

This is an amazing dashboard and i love everything about it.
Problem is, now i start load testing my server. hundreds of consumers are involved. (although on a different machine)

And when a "big"(1000 concurrent users) traffic starts hitting my activemq the dashboard client is not responding and is extremely slow that its barely usable

any ideas why?

thanks

Comment: What version of hawtio are you using? Is it the one out of box from Apache ActiveMQ 5.9.0? There has been many releases since of hawtio - http://hawt.io/

Answer (score 0):

Is it just the dashboard page or the whole console?  First suggestion is to go to the preferences and dial back the refresh rate; the console's requests have to contend with those 1000 users after all

Also if it's in the same JVM as ActiveMQ, maybe ActiveMQ is kinda hogging most of the available threads to service those users.  You can always run hawtio in a separate JVM and use the "Connect" page to connect to the ActiveMQ JVM.  This may specifically help for hawtio's HTML templates, as these get served from the same war, though they should only be downloaded once and then cached.

Comment: the whole console. what do u mean dial back? set it to 30 seconds?

Comment: yeah, 30 seconds.  Maybe we need longer options too like 1 or 5 minutes.

Comment: btw we did an improvement in latest hawtio about limiting how deep nested we go in jmx trees. It may help on this dashboard too.